# Method to link logged Author to Article they created not working

Tags: python, django

Something is wrong with my method, assign_article_creator. It's supposed to populate the field, custom_user, with the username (email address) of the logged-in user/author, so that the author is associated with any article that they create. But it's not working. In Django Admin, the field custom_user is populated with '----' when an author creates an article. Please help me. Thank you.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

class Articles(models.Model):
    custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, default=None, null=True, 
           on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

views.py

```
class CreateArticle(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Articles
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name = "users/add_article.html"

    def assign_article_creator(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        form = self.form_class(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.custom_user = request.user
            instance.save()
        return render(request=request, 
            template_name ="users/add_article.html", context={"form": 
            form})
```

Comment: How are you creating an article? I assume the user is loading a form in the browser and entering data, correct? What route does that form post to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend `CreateView`, you can't add just any method name you want to the class and expect it to work automatically. Instead, you need to override `post()` with the custom logic to assign `custom_user`. (You may want to name this `author` instead.) You can also leverage `super().post()` to do most of the work for you. Note that when you override `post()`, you don't need `if request.method == 'POST':` because `CreateView` already does that for you.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to override post() using super().post() within my code above? I have a sense for what you're saying, but I don't have enough experience to execute on it properly. (I can also show my urls.py, forms.py, and templates if they are relevant). Thanks!

Comment: I added this line to CreateView's post method, followed by my code, and it worked:         super(CreateArticle, self).post(request)

Comment: @Condado That is the old Python 2 style. In python 3, `super()` doesn't need any arguments.